# Magento - non eav collection sort order

Tags: magento

In Magento, when using non eav collections what is the best way to add sort orders?

With eav collections i believe there are convenience methods for doing this but with non eav there dont appear to be the same facilities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both Magento collection superclasses ([`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php) and [`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php)) inherit three public convenience methods from the collection superclass [`Varien_Data_Collection_Db`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php):

- [`setOrder()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php#L271)
- [`addOrder()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php#L283), an alias for `setOrder()`
- [`unshiftOrder()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php#L295), for moving a sort parameter to the first position

The EAV collection superclass provides another method, [`addAttributeToSort()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php#L351), which ensures that the attribute is joined on to the collection for sorting.

As [Vinai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485589/vinai) has [pointed out on his tumblr](http://tweetorials.tumblr.com/post/11137227678/magento-collection-ordering-or-sorting), there are some considerations in how and when these methods will behave.

Answer (score 4):

The only method that worked for me for sorting custom module collection (flat collection) is to use as:

```
$sortField = 'field-goes-here';
$direction = 'ASC'; //or 'DESC'
$collection->getSelect()->order($sortField , $direction);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
$_productCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($_category)->setOrder('field-goes-here', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection->getSelect()->order($sortField , $direction);
```

Replace by:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order($sortField . $direction);
```

order expect 1 param